# Best practices for organizing the structure of folders and files in a Lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am creating a Lib to make available via npm and would like to know the best practices for organizing the structure of folders and files.

Should I also minify and make available in a **dist/**?

Currently my structure looks like this:

```
|--⫸  tree                                                                                                                                              
.
├── README.md
├── index.js
├── lib
│   ├── item1.js
│   ├── item2.js
│   ├── item3.js
│   └── item4.js
└── package.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you provided is almost correct.

Index.js should just export the lib modules that you would like to available for the users.

The only thing it's missing is a tests folder. Despite that, I think it's ok

Comment: Thanks for your answer